# ¿Cómo adquirió la locución "de par en par" su significado?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Se le atribuye a Albert Einstein la famosa frase que dice que “no entiendes realmente algo hasta que eres capaz de explicárselo a tu abuela”.

Ayer por la noche estaba leyendo "Yo puedo leer con los ojos cerrados" del Dr. Seuss a mi hijo (bueno, al contrario, me lo estaba leyendo él a mi) y de vez en cuando le explicaba el significado de alguna palabra que fuese más rebuscada. La expresión "abrir los ojos **de par en par**" apareció en el libro y quise explicarle el significado, y eso me hizo darme cuenta de que esta es una de esas expresiones o locuciones en las que la suma de las distintas palabras que forman la expresión no tiene nada que ver con el significado de la locución.

La locución por supuesto aparece documentada en el DLE en la entrada de "[par](https://dle.rae.es/par?m=form)", junto a otras muchas locuciones

> **de par en par**

> 1. loc. adv. Dicho de abrir las puertas o ventanas: enteramente.

> 2. loc. adv. Sin impedimento ni obstáculo que estorbe; clara o patentemente.

En algunas de estas locuciones sí podemos observar que "par" conserva el sentido de alguna de las acepciones en esta entrada (sobre todo con la primera acepción de *Igual o semejante totalmente.*: a par/a pares, al par, ir a la par).

Sin embargo en otras, como es el caso de "de par en par" es mucho menos intuitivo. El significado de la expresión no se deduce de forma natural de las palabras que la forman.

¿Cómo adquirió la locución "de par en par" su significado? ¿A qué "par" nos referimos en esta expresión?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suele ser una ventaja que la expresión sea antigua, como lo es en este caso, dado que los diccionarios de Covarrubias y el *Autoridades* de los siglos XVII y XVIII, respectivamente, son más dados a explicar las expresiones.

En este caso podemos leer lo siguiente en el *Autoridades* (1737):

> De *par* en *par*. Phrase adverb. con que se significa estar abiertas enteramente las puertas, ò ventanas: como quien dice, que el par de hojas, de que regularmente se componen, está abierto igualmente.

Por la definición sabemos que un *par* son dos cosas de la misma especie. Si te fijas, las ventanas suelen tener dos hojas iguales (antiguamente, al menos), los ojos tienen dos párpados iguales, etc. La frase se refiere a que de un objeto del par al otro objeto del par, ambos se abren por igual.

> *Echando mano a un çerrojo de una ventana, abryóla de par en par.*
>
> Anónimo, "La corónica de Adramón", c 1492 (España).

Comment: Y con esta publicación llego a la bonita cifra de [1000 respuestas (y 500 preguntas)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awHi5.png). :-)

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! Que sean unos cuantos miles más (a los humanos [nos sale algo menos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qapq.png), por cierto jeje, como mod te suman las borradas)

Comment: ¿Podría explicar el significado de la locución en "La luna de par en par" presente en el poema "La sangre derramada"?

Answer (score 3):

### ¿Cómo adquirió la locución “de par en par” su significado?

[image: foto de una ventana de dos piezas]

Me parece que tienen que ver con el mecanismo de las ventanas. Éstas tradicionalmente se construían con un cerramiento de dos piezas, es decir, con un par de hojas sujetas verticalmente mediante bisagras a los costados de un marco. La expresión "abrir las ventanas de par en par" se entiende por eso, por el acto de plegar **ambas partes** hacia el exterior.

Por lo mismo la locución aplicada a la apertura de ojos se funda en el paralelo (metafórico) de los ojos con ventanas.